# Best way to convert Locale properties names to normal names

Tags: java, regex, string

I am reading a list of file property file names from a bundle.
I need to replace file contents are in following format `{en_GB==My name}`

I am using `replaceAll` method to replace the following characters `"{en_GB" and "}"`
I can have any number of `=` symbols and the string `"en_"` may end with GB or `AU` or `US` etc.

What would be the best way to replace these?

```
String s = "{en_GB==kt!hibio}";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[{\\W}]", ""));
```

Comment: Could you please post your code? Otherwise, it is impossible to check what problem you are having.

Comment: if `{en_GB==My name}` is your input ,what's your output?

Comment: My output shoule be "My name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
String s = "{en_GB==pm!name}";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\{\\w+=+([^}]+)}", "$1"));
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/3BHZJA)

The regex matches

- `\\{` - a literal `{`
- `\\w+` - 1 or more alphanumerics or an underscore
- `=+` - 1 or more equal signs
- `([^}]+)` - matches and captures into Group 1 one or more characters other than a `}`
- `}` - a closing brace

When the substring is matched, all the matched text is replaced with just the text captured into Group 1 with `$1`.

Your solution does not work because the regex you have is matching 1 character that is either `{` or a non-word character (`\W`) and a literal `}` because you enclosed the expression into sqaure brackets, thus forming a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Now, since this regex is quite generic, you may further narrow down its matching capabilities like this:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?i)\\{en_[a-z]+=+([^}]+)}", "$1"));
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/gt6f7P)

This `en_[a-z]+` will be required, and - as the `(?i)` makes the pattern case insensitive - will match `en_US` or `EN_US`.

In case you know there are just 2 letters after `en_`, use a [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{2}`:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?i)\\{en_[a-z]{2}=+([^}]+)}", "$1"));
```

Comment: I will add a comment why your approach does not work.

Comment: How does the regex identifies en_GB and en_US ? also what is $1 ? sorry I am dumb in these regex

Comment: This regex is quote generic. Let me add an alternative.

Comment: Should I use the second solution instead of the first one? I have confused as the first one is also working.

Comment: I think you can safely use the last one *unless* there are cases like `en_AUS`. I hope I clarified the regex syntax enough for you to be able to further adjust the pattern for your needs. `"\\{\\w+=+([^}]+)}"` will match `{12_3=====!@ #$we rw34}`, `"(?i)\\{en_[a-z]+=+([^}]+)}"` will match `{en_ddfdffdfds====34 2yh %$&`) and `"(?i)\\{en_[a-z]{2}=+([^}]+)}"` will match `{en_sd===E#@r  34rf3434}`. Since